# Dosbox gets muted when not focused

Tags: dosbox

I'd like to hear the sound output while it is not focused. Is there an option for it?

Comment: :O Mine won't shutup when its out of focus!

Comment: That means there MUST be an option for it... >:I

Comment: Hmmm, checked your config? I just run it on a Windows 8 computer. Play F19 Stealth Fighter and even when I tab out its breaking my eardrums with the screech.

Comment: How many cores does your CPU have? Have you reset the config options back to the defaults? What games have you tried?

Comment: My CPU has 4 cores, so far I tried with **Earthworm Jim 1 & 2**, and **Pro Pinball: Timeshock**. The ones from GOG pre-configured.

Comment: Hmm. I don't have those games. Try taking it out of full screen. True full screen will not play sound when minimized, AFAIK. However, borderless FS windows will not go silent when minimized. I read somewhere recently that that's how you can tell what mode you're in.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I got is by playing with the **priority** option. Back then I had it in:

> priority=**higher,normal**

Setting this to **highest,highest** would try to make the game work generally (with sound and everything), even when not focused. Although this isn't working at all *(i.e. if I focus the Chrome browser, Dosbox will still be silenced)*.